# Learning MimeType on active files, through Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-forms, drive

I will create an Add-on.
I want it to work for docs, sheets and forms. To make the menu, I need to know the file-type. How do I find it?

I could use DriveApp to check MimeType, but I will need the fileId.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve it but the add-on-menu is not working properly. Worked once, then never again.

```
 function onOpen(e) {
  var menu;
  if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() != null)
    menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu();
  else if(DocumentApp.getActiveDocument() != null)
    menu = DocumentApp.getUi().createAddonMenu();
  else if(FormApp.getActiveForm() != null)
    menu = FormApp.getUi().createAddonMenu();
  if(menu)
    menu
    .addItem('Text', 'func1')
    .addToUi();
}
```